# AngularJS - Use multiple controllers across bootstrap tabs

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to divide content with bootstrap tabs. This works fine except the html breaks when I attach the ng-controller in parent elements. Is there a way to use html elements to insert ng-controller without affecting the hierarchy necessary to display tabs in bootstrap?

Working tab layout:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">{{ tab1_content }}</div> 
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade in">{{ tab2_content }}</div> 
    <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade in">{{ tab3_content }}</div> 
  </div> <!-- all tab-content -->
</div> <!-- end myApp -->
```

How I'd like to use my controllers (breaks the tab displays by putting content in all tabs:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="tab-content">
    <ng-controller ng-controller="test_controller1">   
      <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">{{ tab1_content }}</div> 
      <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade in">{{ tab2_content }}</div> 
    </ng-controller> <!-- end test_controller1 -->
    <ng-controller ng-controller="test_controller2">   
      <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade in">{{ tab3_content }}</div> 
    </ng-controller> <!-- end test_controller2 -->
  </div> <!-- all tab-content -->
</div> <!-- end myApp -->
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/L2b4yLfa/

Comment: FishBulbX i followed this approach and it solved loading different controller for each tab https://github.com/rpocklin/ui-router-tabs

Comment: you shouldn't be using bootstrap with angular, you should use [UI Bootstrap
Bootstrap components written in pure AngularJS by the AngularUI ](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

Comment: Thanks for the comments and suggestions... I do see that my current approach is not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Is this acceptable?

I have initialized the same controller for two tabs. Since its a small window the code snippet output will show mobile view. click on `run code snippet -> full page`

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.module('myApp').controller('test_controller1', function($scope) {
 $scope.tab1_content = "Tab One Content";
 $scope.tab2_content = "Tab Two Content";
});

angular.module('myApp').controller('test_controller2', function($scope) {
 $scope.tab3_content = "Tab Three Content";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Tab 2</a></li> 
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Tab 3</a></li> 
   </ul>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>Testing</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="tab1" ng-controller="test_controller1" class="tab-pane fade in active">{{ tab1_content }}</div> 
      <div id="tab2" ng-controller="test_controller1" class="tab-pane fade in">{{ tab2_content }}</div> 
      <div id="tab3" ng-controller="test_controller2" class="tab-pane fade in">{{ tab3_content }}</div> 
  </div> <!-- all tab-content -->
</div> <!-- end myApp -->
```

So in the future you would need to share data between the same controller for the two tabs using services.

Comment: Yes... I thought of that... and the issue of creating two scopes for test_controller1 would be problematic. Not sure if it is worth the effort for a simple layout issue.

Comment: It all depends on the situation and whether the tab1 and tab2 really need to communicate, if the communication is minimal then go for a third controller(one for each tab) or even a single controller for all three tabs( but I dont think we can use a single controller for two adjacent elements without it being as a parent element), services can be used to share the variables.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to switch to angular bootstrap ui, not use the built-in uib-tabs and use $rootscope to handle the 'active_tab' value.

```
<style> .uib-tab.nav-item { display:none; } .nav-tabs { border-bottom: inherit; } </style>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-click="navCollapsed = !navCollapsed">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
    </div> <!-- end navbar-header -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" uib-collapse="navCollapsed">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ng-class="{active: active_tab == 1}" ng-click="active_tab = 1"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active: active_tab == 2}" ng-click="active_tab = 2"><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li> 
        <li ng-class="{active: active_tab == 3}" ng-click="active_tab = 3"><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li> 
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Selected Tab: {{ active_tab }}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- end uib-collapse -->
  </nav> <!-- end nav -->

  <uib-tabset active="active_tab">
    <ng-controller ng-controller="test_controller1">
      <uib-tab index="1" heading="heading not displayed">1: {{ tab1_content }}</uib-tab>
      <uib-tab index="2" heading="heading not displayed">2: {{ tab2_content }}</uib-tab>
    </ng-controller>
    <ng-controller ng-controller="test_controller2">
      <uib-tab index="3" heading="heading not displayed">3: {{ tab3_content }}</uib-tab>
    </ng-controller>
  </uib-tabset>
</div>
```

Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/36tkl3pCV7hgNz8rbpTq?p=preview